# No active Desktop in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3

I am running Linux Mint 18.2 64-bit from an external HDD with Gnome 3 as the desktop. I have several `*.desktop` files in my `Desktop` folder. But, they are not showing up. I have tried installing `gnome-tweak-tools` and toggling  `Icons on Desktop` but it does nothing.

How can I get my desktop to be active? Thanks!

**EDIT** : I really don't think the issue is my `*.desktop` files because they are just the ones that come with the apps. But, in case there is something weird with gnome, here it is one of them:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=pidgin
X-AppInstall-Popcon=3151
X-AppInstall-Keywords= pigeon;gaim;chat;windows;live;aim
X-AppInstall-Section=main
Name=Pidgin Internet Messenger
GenericName=Internet Messenger
Comment=Chat over IM.  Supports AIM, Google Talk, Jabber/XMPP, MSN, Yahoo and more
Exec=pidgin
Icon=pidgin
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
X-MessagingMenu-UsesChatSection=true
X-MessagingMenu-UsesChatSection=true



X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=app-install-data`
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post the contents of one/some of your *.desktop files? It could be that they are not properly formatted.

(I would have just commented, but apparently I don't have enough points to do so)

**Edit:** I apologize. I didn't read your question carefully & didn't realize that the *real* issue was that the desktop was not active & the icons were not showing up (even with the fact that the title is very clear).

I do not use Gnome 3, but there is some info around the web on its desktop configuration. [This post](http://joesteiger.com/2011/07/02/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-gnome-3-gnome-shell-ubuntu-11-04/), by Joe Steiger, says to launch *dconf-editor* & navigate to "*org > gnome > desktop > background*" & check the box labeled "*show-desktop-icons*".

[image]

I should have remembered about *dconf-editor*. I don't think I've used it since I started using Linux Mint with Cinnamon desktop. Anyway, I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I added it to the question. Too long to put in a comment.

Comment: Okay, it looks alright to me. Are your .desktop files marked as executable? I believe some desktop environments only properly recognize them if the executable bit is set: `$ sudo chmod +x my_desktop_file.desktop`. Or change executable properties from your desktop environment's **right-click -> Properties** option, if available.

Comment: Yes. They are marked as executable. I checked both the files and the menu which you mention before posting this. It's behaving as if there is a recommended package missing. In other words, it's working just fine otherwise, just this functionality isn't available for some reason.

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry about my misunderstanding.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` if the files belong to you. Only use `sudo` if you really need to do so.

Comment: Thank you roaima. I didn't remember if `chmod` required elevated privileges. I remember there are some commands that require it no matter what.